# Clean link for mirror site

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've created a mirror site and the URL format I have is as follows:

For reqular articles:
http://my.mirror.site/mirrored.site.name.as.directory/directory/index-Article.php?title=Article

For translated articles:
http://my.mirror.site/mirrored.site.name.as.directory/directory/index-Article/langcode.php?title=Article/langcode

I've managed to remove everything after .php using this (the htaccess file is in the same directory as indexed articles):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .+
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mirrored.site.name.as.directory/directory/$1? [R=301,L]
```

So it cleans up the URL a little bit and I remain with:
my.mirror.site/mirrored.site.name.as.directory/directory/index-Article.php

But ideally I'd like for it to be something like this:
my.mirror.site/Article
my.mirror.site/Article/langcode

Any ideas how this could be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Following rules are to be written in `my.mirror.site`. The rules should be written as below.

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)/(.*)$ /mirrored.site.name.as.directory/directory/index-Article/langcode.php?title=$1/$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /mirrored.site.name.as.directory/directory/index-Article.php?title=$1 [R=301,L]
```

So, for e-g  user hits `http://my.mirror.site/switzerland` It will redirect to `http://my.mirror.site/mirrored.site.name.as.directory/directory/index-Article.php?title=switzerland`

If there is any arguments, it will also be appended with the new URL

Comment: Article equals to the name of an article, so it has to equal to whatever the user inputs. Same with langcode, it can be: et, tl, it, ro and about 20 others. Would this just redirect or actually make the links from longer URLs redirect to a clean one?

Comment: To make it replace article dynamically, I changed my answer. please check

Comment: I made further corrections by changing article.php to $1.php, but absolutely nothing happens.

Comment: Also, I'm not interested in having my.mirror.site/article redirected, but masked. E.g. when a person hits my.mirror.site/Article_name it doesn't change the URL.